# Как определить высоту TitledPane после раскрытия панели

Tags: java, javafx

После раскрытия панели TitledPane  метод getHeight() возвращает высоту закрытой панели. Метод isExpanded() возвращает true/
После закрытия - наоборот: высоту раскрытой. То есть возвращается старое значение.
Метод getHeight() применяю в обработке "On Mouse Released", когда мышкой раскрываешь панель.

Comment: Когда срабатывает событие мыши, анимация сворачивания/разворачивания только начинается. В этот момент свойство isExpanded уже изменило значение, но высота еще старая. Можно либо отключить анимацию, и добавить listener к свойству `heightProperty()` (если не отключить анимацию, то будут фиксироваться все промежуточные высоты между свернутым и развернутым состоянием), либо проверять высоту через какой-то промежуток времени (когда анимация закончится).

Comment: Такая мысль была. Во первых убрал анимацию, во вторых поставил задержку при обработке "On Mouse Released" (до 6 секнд) - результат прежний. Только приложение повесит 6 секунд.
Всё таки у меня ощущение, что использую не то событие.

Comment: Ну так если Thread.sleep делать, то графический интерфейс и будет зависать. Нужно в отдельном потоке ждать. Я бы через delayed executor и CompletableFuture делал, см. второй пример в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58708611

Comment: listener к свойству prefHeightProperty() ставил, но на него управление не передаётся. наверное я что то не так делаю. Сейчас попробую с heightProperty()

Comment: prefHeightProperty - это предпочитаемая (preffered) высота, она не меняется во время анимации. Нужно следить за фактической высотой.

Comment: В целом с  listener к свойству heightProperty() все идет как ожидалось.
Всё ОК!СПАСИБО, а т

Comment: Добавил ответом, с примерами для обоих вариантов, о которых я писал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда срабатывает событие мыши, анимация сворачивания/разворачивания только начинается. В этот момент свойство `isExpanded` уже изменило значение, но высота еще старая.

Можно либо отключить анимацию, и добавить `listener` к свойству `heightProperty()` (если не отключить анимацию, то будут фиксироваться все промежуточные значения высоты между свернутым и развернутым состоянием):

```
titledPane.setAnimated(false);
titledPane.heightProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> 
    System.out.printf("%s %f\n",
            titledPane.isExpanded() ? "Expanded" : "Collapsed",
            titledPane.getHeight())));
```

Пример вывода:

```
Expanded 157,000000
Collapsed 26,000000
```

Также можно проверять высоту через небольшой промежуток времени (чтобы анимация успела завершиться):

```
titledPane.setAnimated(true);
titledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.printf("%s %f\n",
                titledPane.isExpanded() ? "Expanded" : "Collapsed", titledPane.getHeight()),
                CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
```

Вывод:

```
Collapsed 26,000000
Expanded 157,000000
```

Задержка через `Thread.sleep` в основном потоке не поможет, т.к. анимация (и вообще графический интерфейс) работает в этом же потоке, из-за этого графический интерфейс подвиснет на время задержки (в итоге анимация остановится и продолжится только после окончания задержки, а не будет выполняться во время нее). Но можно использовать `Thread.sleep` внутри отдельного потока, например внутри `runnable`, переданного в `CompletableFuture.runAsync` в примере выше (как альтернатива `delayedExecutor`):

```
titledPane.setAnimated(true);
titledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.printf("%s %f\n",
                titledPane.isExpanded() ? "Expanded" : "Collapsed", titledPane.getHeight())
        });
```